# setFEHostURL in weblogic is not setting the front end host

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g, wlst

I am trying to set the front end host & I ran the below using wlst

```
readDomain(“/Test1/data/user_projects/domains/compact_domain”) 
setFEHostURL(“http://apc-testdemos:443”,”https://apc-testdemos:443”,”false”) 
updateDomain()
closeDomain()
exit()
```

I also tried the above in a clustered env.

I am not seeing any updates to the config.xml file.

I don't see it updating the front end host and ports. Any help?

Comment: Do you have any error or exception when you setFEHostURL? Is that http and https both are using same port?

Comment: I don't see any errors. I changed the http port also. Is there any log wlst generates that can be looked into?

Comment: I see the below in the log which seems fine: succeed: read domain from "Test1/data/user_projects/domains/compact_domain" succeed: validateConfig "KeyStorePasswords" oracle.security.jps.util.JpsUtil - JpsUtil: isAuditDisabled set to true com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainRegistryWrapper - need to initialize domainRegistrydocument object WARNING [18] oracle.security.opss.tools.lifecycle.ProductArtifactsConfigImpl - No templates are processed, please call processXXX() methods
Domain Extension Successful! succeed: update domain

Comment: I also see backup backup_config2.xml files getting created.

Comment: If you are working in interactive mode check for dumpStack() that will shows you last errors/exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the following option at your WLST prompt:

```
wls:/offline> debug('true')
Debug is now turned on.
```

Then you can try to with the your commands set.

Alternatively you can see:

```
set('DebugEnabled', 'true')
```

Comment: Debug was turned on, no errors or messages. Log shows the same as before but no update to config.xml

Comment: Now instead of updateDomain() use writeDomain(domain_home) let us know what you have...

Comment: writeDomain("....") says Domain already exists at the specified location. Change the domain location.

Comment: before the writeDomain() use the 
setOption('OverwriteDomain', 'true')

Comment: setOption is throwing Config option "OverwriteDomain" not allowed error.